# Property 'SVG' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, expo, apexcharts

I have installed `react-apexchart` in my react native expo project. While importing chart, the error is showing:

```
ERROR  ReferenceError: Property 'SVG' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "biarrow_v1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "apexcharts": "^3.43.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.10",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

What would be the solution? How can I use **ApexChart** in my React Native Expo project?

Comment: Can you add your import related code ?

Comment: imported :

    ``import Chart from "react-apexcharts";``